# Is it possible to access a memory block allocated by cudaHostAlloc with cudaHostAllocPortable flag from a different process?

Tags: process, cuda

CUDA documentation says that portable memory blocks can be accessed from all contexts, does this mean we can use such blocks across processes? Specifically, I want to pass this host pointer to a different process that will copy to device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Portable memory Can be used by many host thread, not process. Actually, pinned memory is only available to the thread malloc it if not portable.

You should use IPC to share memory between process.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is only accessible within the same process. Use you should use cudaIpc... or the OS's IPC.